# Is studying in a university while at a yeshiva possible in israel?

Tags: torah-study, eretz-yisrael, adult-learning, college-university-school

I would like to learn in Israel in a university, but besides that i would like to study in a yeshiva. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to mi.yodeya, Andrew!

Comment: If such a thing were possible, can you imagine how swamped with work you would be? As if university and yeshiva alone were hard enough, you want to mash them together to form some scary Frankenstein monster!? :P

Comment: There are programs for just that option. One thing to look in to would be the Touro options.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Of course, it's always possible to attend both a yeshiva and secular university pretty much in any geographic place that has both. Israel is certainly no different in that aspect. With that said, I'd prefer if you could edit your question, if you are specifically looking for dual program schools - i.e. where you do both in one place. That's not obvious from your question.

Comment: @ezra Both of us know many students who manage to take a dual program. It is challenging and it does make for a rather long day. But, at least within the NY City area, these days, it's starting to become the "norm" among Ortho. Jews. I say **starting** b/c there are still many yeshivot discouraging kids going to college. I won't discuss the many problems that idea can cause down the line. But, of those that are doing a dual program that I have met, not one is a monster. If anything, they are exhausted but very smart successful people. Andrew would be the same way, I believe.

Comment: @DanF - Yeah, but let's not pretend it would be a piece of cake.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I'll check them:)
Of course i know it's important to speak hebrew And not just for learning porpuses. Im working on that also.

Answer (score 7):

[Machon Lev](http://www.jct.ac.il/en) in Jerusalem is one such option

> The Jerusalem College of Technology (JCT) – Lev Academic Center is the
>   second largest academic institution in Jerusalem. It is fully
>   accredited by Israel’s Council of Higher Education and specializes in
>   high-tech engineering, computer science, industrial management and
>   health sciences combined with a Jewish studies program. JCT’s mission
>   is to produce leaders who are strongly committed to Israel, to
>   Jerusalem and to Jewish values.

Answer (score 5):

Bar Ilan offers the option of combining beit midrash for part of the day and university courses the rest of the day: http://mgl.org.il/

Comment: As far as I see, it is in hebrew, I dint even find the english version of the site, so first I would have to perfect my hebrew, right?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, you'd need to be proficient in Hebrew.

Comment: Judging from your comments, it appears that your Hebrew knowledge is "deficient"? Perhaps an idea is seeking out one of the various "American one year" yeshivot that abound in Israel. While they are usually geared for post high school students (and I'm uncertain of your age), I would imagine that they have no problem if you join in. (Trust me, they're happy to accept your money!) and attending any secular Israeli university.

Comment: @Andrew Whenever you are going to be moving from one country to another, especially to learn, it's always a good idea to be proficient in the local language. We English speakers are usually pampered because so many people in other countries know our language.